# How do I preserve the history file of cygwin bash across independent sessions?

Tags: bash, command-history, cygwin

So my home directory does have a .bash_history file, but it refuses to grow any bigger for some reason. I've already changed the `.bashrc` settings to set the history size to 99999 and the history file size limit to something similar.

Comment: Which settings did you change? How big does `.bash_history` get? Do you want a single history file for all sessions or several history files?

Comment: I just set export HISTSIZE=9999 and export HISTFILESIZE=999999. I want a single history file for all sessions.

Answer (score 12):

Find this in .bashrc:

`# Make bash append rather than overwrite the history on disk`

`# shopt -s histappend`

and uncomment the second line!

Comment: where is bashrc?